# Datalab fails to read the Bigquery data on dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

datalab is installed on dataproc 1 node cluster on gcp.

Following query run successfully :
`%%bq tables describe --name "datalab-dev-xxx.ML_PP_xxx.ML_CAMPN30_xxx"`

While data read query fails with error:
`SELECT * FROM 'datalab-dev-xxx.ML_PP_xxx.ML_CAMPN30_xxx' WHERE partition_day = "2019-05-22" LIMIT 10`

Error : 
HTTP request failed: Not found: Job datalab-dev-238506:job_JT_cgX84NyJQRt-F_DmKl5YM44hb

Any hint about the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the `datalab-dev-xxx.ML_PP_xxx` dataset is not based in the US location.  Consider using a recent release of google-cloud-bigquery instead, as it knows how to handle autodetected locations properly when issuing queries.  The old datalab library does not process this correctly, and is looking for the job in the wrong location.

See [this migration article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datalab-migration) for more information about switching usage over to a newer library.

Comment: Thanks! I did try to use the  google-cloud-bigquery but still getting below errors: `__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`                                                      Executed command:                                                                                   
                                                                                                                    
 %%bigquery
SELECT *, EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM cmp_day) as dayofweek  FROM datalab-xx-238506.ML_XX_DATASETS.ML_XX limit 10